# Add data into rows on click

Tags: angularjs

I want that when I insert some data into a textbox and click a button, the data should be inserted in a particular table column, and when i keep on adding the data the rows should keep on increasing with the entered data. Code:

```
var parking = angular.module("parking", []);
parking.controller("parkingCtrl", function($scope){
$scope.carnamebind='';
$scope.car=[];
$scope.bindcarName = function(){
var ee=$scope.car;

ee.push($scope.carname);
$scope.carnamebind=ee;
}
})
```

the html:

```
<body ng-controller="parkingCtrl">
<h3 ng-model="appTitle"></h3>


<table>
<tr>
<td>Car name</td>
<td>Car model</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>{{carnamebind}}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td ><input type="text" ng-model="carname"/><input type="button" ng-click="bindcarName()"/></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

</table>


</body>
```

2 problems are coming:

1) All pushed data into array is inserted in the same column

2) Data is inserted in the form of array, like `["sd","sdasd"]`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.carnamebind= [
    "Alfreds Futterkiste",
    "Berglunds snabbköp",
    "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
    "Ernst Handel",
  ];
$scope.bindcarName = function(ee){

$scope.carnamebind.push(ee);


}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<table ng-controller="myCtrl" border="1">
<tr>
<td>Car name</td>
<td>Car model</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in carnamebind">

  <td>{{x}}</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td ><input type="text" ng-model="carname"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" ng-click="bindcarName(carname)"/></td>
</tr>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```